# Label width in Google Charts

Tags: api, charts

I am trying to have a fixed width size for the labels in my Google chars. The problem is that I am showing several charts, one below the other. Since the y axis is filled with the names of people, depending on the names' lengths, I get a wider or narrower lebel area. The final result is ugly because each chart has a different label width and worst of all, the area where the data is actually shown is wider or narrower. I would like all of them to be aligned. Just to make sure I make myself understood, I am posting a very dirty solution below. While trying, I came up with this (I am not keeping). See the ______________ line as if it was one item. When using this huge line, all my labels get aligned, but the result is poor. Besides being ugly, it steals the position that would be occupied by one of the names. Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks!

```
![<img src="https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=750x134&cht=bhg&chco=FF9900,FFCC99&chg=10,0,2,5&chbh=12,3,15&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|1:|______________________________|Carlos+Roberto+Ramos|Antonio+Rodrigues|Ana+Rosa|&chxs=1,666666,14,1&chd=t:10,20,20,-1&chm=r,a0bae9,0,0,0.20|r,356bd0,0,0.20,0.202" />][1]
```

[1]: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Another **very** dirty way to do this is to calculate the number of chars in the longest label you are using then multiply by a fudge factor to return the pixel length of the label. For this i used 4.8px as that seemed about right...

I then added this value to an arbitrary value for the size of the bar-area (250 in my case) and right-aligned the charts

This produces *pretty* good results, but there is some movement depending on the characters contained in the labels (due to font kerning).

See below for the VBA code i used to generate the label width value (as the charts were being generated using Access):

```
Function labelSizePx()
    Dim label_array
    label_array(0) = "foo"
    label_array(1) = "goo"
    label_array(2) = "bar"
    label_array(3) = "foogoobar"

    Dim lng_str
    lng_str = ""

    For i = 0 To UBound(label_array)
        If Len(label_array(i)) > Len(lng_str) Then lng_str = label_array(i)
    Next i

    Dim char_px
    char_px = 4.8


    labelSizePx = CInt(Len(lng_str) * char_px)

    ' returns 43px in this case

End Function
```

This could possibly be improved by outputting the longest label into a <span> element (or similar) and calculating the actual width of the string, as the above method attempts to estimate the kerning of the font using the fudge factor.

Comment: An image would be great with this answer. :)